# TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from string storage ref[] storage ref to string memory requested

Tags: solidity, hardhat

The problem is in this line:   carObject.maintenance

```
    carObject.maintenance.push(newMaintenance);
    // _carMaintenance[tokenId].push(newMaintenance);

    emit MaintenanceAdded(
        // ownerOf(tokenId),
        // tokenId,
        carObject.vin,
        // carObject.repairs,
        carObject.maintenance
    );
}
```

Comment: Please paste the relevant code. The initialization of the array at least